# serializing enum and addind description

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an enum as such:

```
public enum DriveConfig
{
    [Description("4X2")]
    FOURXTWO=0,

    [Description("4x4")]
    FOURXFOUR=1,

    [Description("6x2")]
    SIXBYTWO=2,

    [Description("6x4")]
    SIXBYFOUR=3

}
```

And in my system I can get the description out nice and easy with something like this:

```
public static string GetDescriptionFromEnumValue(Enum value)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute attribute = value.GetType()
            .GetField(value.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
            .SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;
        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }
```

works really nicely.

But now i need to extend the system with webservices,so I am making dto's of my objects, and serializing them. straight forward. but how can I include the description on the other end?

I tried this

```
[DataContract]
public enum DriveConfigDto
{
    [Description("4X2")]
    [EnumMember]
    FOURXTWO=0,

    [Description("4x4")]
    [EnumMember]
    FOURXFOUR=1,

    [Description("6x2")]
    [EnumMember]        
    SIXBYTWO=2,

    [Description("6x4")]
    [EnumMember]
    SIXBYFOUR=3
}
```

but I cant access the description on the other end

Comment: How do you "unpack" the enum on the other side?

Comment: exactly. thats the problem.

Comment: hehe ok. *how* have you *tried* to unpack the enum? What does the Enum look like on the reciver end?

Comment: like a normal enum, minus the description :)

Comment: then thats way it won't work. the new enums doesn't have the description attribute. Simple as that :) If you realle need the description I suggest you use a class (or something) instead of enum.. I don't think enums was designed to have a description..

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, as these attributes are not automatically serialized.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can use the Value property of EnumMemberAttribute:

```
[DataContract]
public enum DriveConfigDto
{
    [EnumMember(Value="4X2")]
    FOURXTWO=0,

    [EnumMember]
    FOURXFOUR=1,

    [EnumMember]        
    SIXBYTWO=2,
}
```

The resulting XSD will look like:

```
<xs:simpleType name="">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="4X2"/>
<xs:enumeration value="FOURXFOUR"/>
<xs:enumeration value="SIXBYTWO"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Let's make task more complicated: `[Description("4 X 2")]`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in common case, because there can be non-.NET client for your web-service (hence, it knows nothing about attributes, because attributes are not a part of contract).

But if you're limited with .NET on client side, you can share contracts assembly between server and clients.

Comment: true. for now, the client is actually in my control so it will be in .net. just thinking as a type this: move the original (non serialized) enum into it's own dll that all projects can see (original website, new web service, new client app. and then on the client side transform back from dto to domain

Answer (score 0):

before you add a service reference you have to reference the assemby in which the enum is definded in and add it to the reuse assembly list while adding the service reference.